# Eclipse Neon Crashes on startup on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: eclipse, macos, crash, eclipse-neon, macos-high-sierra

I have MacOS High Sierra, I downloaded eclipse Neon and I moved the file to the application folder. When I start eclipse and select a new workspace it shows the intro window for a second and it suddently closes. When I start eclipse again with the previous workspace I get the following error:

```
See the log file /Users/...../workspace/.metadata/.log
```

and the following lines are the content of the log file:

```
!SESSION 2017-08-08 20:01:14.727 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/saadaoui/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/saadaoui/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2017-08-08 20:01:23.777
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:27.856
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.drawTabBody(CTabRendering.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.draw(CTabRendering.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onPaint(CTabFolder.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:27.865
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemImageForID(Display.java:1948)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemImage(Display.java:1984)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.LabelProviderWrapper.getSWTImage(LabelProviderWrapper.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.LabelProviderWrapper.getImage(LabelProviderWrapper.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.createTitleArea(InternalDialog.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.createDialogArea(InternalDialog.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$3.eventLoopException(Workbench.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.handle(PartRenderingEngine.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1133)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:27.868
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.drawTabBody(CTabRendering.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.draw(CTabRendering.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onPaint(CTabFolder.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:27.929
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.drawTabBody(CTabRendering.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.draw(CTabRendering.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onPaint(CTabFolder.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:27.930
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemImageForID(Display.java:1948)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemImage(Display.java:1984)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.LabelProviderWrapper.getSWTImage(LabelProviderWrapper.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.LabelProviderWrapper.getImage(LabelProviderWrapper.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.createTitleArea(InternalDialog.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.createDialogArea(InternalDialog.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopException(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$3.eventLoopException(Workbench.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.handle(PartRenderingEngine.java:1143)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1133)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:27.933
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.drawTabBody(CTabRendering.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.draw(CTabRendering.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onPaint(CTabFolder.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:28.066
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.drawTabBody(CTabRendering.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering.draw(CTabRendering.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onPaint(CTabFolder.java:2035)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Control.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Widget.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5711)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Display.java:5084)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5465)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(NSApplication.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3700)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-08-08 20:01:28.068
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemImageForID(Display.java:1948)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemImage(Display.java:1984)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.LabelProviderWrapper.getSWTImage(LabelProviderWrapper.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.LabelProviderWrapper.getImage(LabelProviderWrapper.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.createTitleArea(InternalDialog.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.createDialogArea(InternalDialog.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.createContents(Dialog.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:101)
.....
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Eclipse didn't like the beta 4 version of MacOS High Sierra so I updated the OS to beta 5 version and Eclipse worked without any issues.